# how to make angular application read environment variables from private cloud foundry (Runtime)

Tags: angular, pcf, private-cloud

I am working with angular 5 application and deploying to private cloud foundry.
In general, while building the application we would provide API endpoint in **"environment.{*}.ts"** file and run **npm run build --prod** command.

my requirement is to read user provided environment variables after deployment.
I am new to PCF.

Thanks in advance.

Links I have tried so far,
[Link1](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html), [Link2](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/node-cfenv),[Link3](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/)

Comment: To clarify, you're wanting to access the environment variables at build time? or run time?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I need to access at run time

Comment: Are you able to leverage Node to do your initial render with Angular Universal?

Comment: I am not familiar with Angular Universal, I will give a look at it.any help in advance is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is to use [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/) to do your initial render server-side via Node.

As part of your Angular Universal setup, you'll have a server.ts file, which can read any environment variables you need. I chose [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) for this example to render the index.html from the Angular application (I'm sure you can use EJS or another templating engine).

```js
// server.ts
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import * as nunjucks from 'nunjucks';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4201;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'index.html')).toString();

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist-server/main.bundle');

const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

nunjucks.configure(DIST_FOLDER, {
  autoescape: true,
  express: app,
});

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');

// Server static files from dist folder
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
// You can pass in server-side values here to have Nunjucks render them
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req, someValue: process.env.someValue });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT);
```

In your index.html, you can output the server-side variables wherever you need. I chose to assign a value to the `window` here called `environment`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/" />
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script>
      window['environment'] = {
        someValue: '{{ someValue }}',
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Subsequently in Angular components, services, etc, you can access the value via `window['environment'].someValue`

Comment: Thank you for your example. I will import and let you know for sure.
as of now, I have come across another approach and deployed.
This one seems interesting :)

Comment: Another way to do this would be to base the `environment.[whatever].ts` file on an environment variable at **build** time and use cross-var: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var to pick up the Node environment variable in the npm build script.

Comment: Thank you,
I have created a `environmentconfig.ts` file during the `ng build --prod` command and then while uploading to PCF we need to use a package.json file. in that Package.json file in the "start" command i had given `ts-node` command to build the `environmentconfig.ts` file.
This file is being build on PCF server hence it is reading the user provided environment variables and building a `environmentconfig.js` file, in the index.html file I am giving the reference to the newly generated `environmentconfig.ts` file. finally, reading `window.environment.{KEY}`, it's working as expected.

Comment: Cool. Glad you were able to get to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [blogpost](https://flores.eken.nl/using-environment-variables-from-cloud-foundry-in-angular-with-the-staticfile_buildpack/) about this. In short:

- Fork the staticfile-buildpack
- Change the `data.go` to include:

```
location /inject {
    default_type application/json;
    return 200 '<%= ENV["INJECT"] %>';
    }
```

- Set a environment var "INJECT" with json in CF
- `cf push` with `-b [your forked repo]`
- enable SSI in the buildpack by including a `Staticfile`
- Add a SSI to your angular `index.html` to include this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">window["INJECT"] = 
            <!--#include virtual="/inject" -->
        </script>
```